# Como ejecuto un comando automaticamente en el dockerfile

Tags: symfony, composer, swagger

Tengo una app desarrollada con symfony (con frontend twig y tambien rutas api).
Realize la documentación de las rutas de la api con la libreria NelmioApiDocBundle(swagger).
Al levantar localmente e ir a la ruta especificada para la documentacion no me cargaba la página y en la consola figuraban los siguientes errores:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://192.168.45.139:7000/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js”. doc:45:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://192.168.45.139:7000/bundles/nelmioapidoc/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js”. doc:46:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://192.168.45.139:7000/bundles/nelmioapidoc/init-swagger-ui.js”. doc:48:1
```

Localmente estos errores los solucioné ejecutando el comando:
`composer require asset`

Ya en producción al cargar la ruta de la documentación vuelvo a tener esos errores.
Mi consulta es si ¿hay alguna forma de ejecutar el comando **composer require asset** al levantar en prod o configurar que se ejecute en el dockerfile o docker-compose?, para no tener que hacerlo manualmente como hice localmente.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1):

Sería en el Dockerfile

```
...
# antes del CMD ó ENTRYPOINT
RUN composer require asset
CMD ...
```

Comment: La respuesta no es muy clara, incluso podría parecer un comentario ¿Puedes mejorarlo? Sino será eliminada.

Comment: @Mateo Si sigues la pregunta entenderias el contexto.

Comment: Solo intento encontrar una explicación al voto negativo que te dieron. Si no quieres mejorar la pregunta, así quedará.